# I got a error when I got the variables of convolution layers in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to got variables of convolution layers and to visualize it.
Then my code is

```
d3 = de_conv(d2, weights2['wc2'], biases2['bc2'], out_shape=[batch_size , c2, c2, 128])
    d3 = batch_norm(d3, epsilon=1e-5, decay=0.9)
    d3 = tf.nn.relu(d3)

    tf.add_to_collection('weight_2', weights2['wc3'])
```

and in test

```
with tf.Session() as sess:

            saver.restore(sess , model_path)
            conv_weights = sess.run([tf.get_collection('weight_2')])
            #visualize the weights
            conv_weights = np.array(conv_weights)

            print(conv_weights.shape)
            vis_square(conv_weights)
```

But I don't understand the conv_weights have a confusing dimensions

```
(1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 128)
```

Answer (score 0):

Weights for conv layers should be `[filter height, filter width, input channels, number of filters (output channels]`. Except for the first two dimensions, your weights fit. Is it just wrapped in two lists? E.g. `[[weights]]` instead of just `weights`.